# if else if for multiple possible values for a variable C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a if-else if construct where in I am setting a particular value of a variable based on the XName Element local name as follows:

```
   public struct UserObject
            {
                public string rawValue;
            }

      var xmlElements= record.Descendants("abc")
         .Select(x => x.Elements().ToArray());


    foreach (XElement[] elements in xmlElements)
            {
      foreach (XElement element in elements)
                {
        UserObject userObject = new UserObject();                       
            if (element.Name.LocalName == "b036") //"b036" is a XML element tag name
              userObject.rawValue = (element.Value.Trim()); //note rawvalue is of string type
            else if (element.Name.LocalName == "b037")
              userObject.rawValue = (element.Value.Trim());
            else if (element.Name.LocalName == "b040")
              userObject.rawValue = (element.Value.Trim());
           }
```

For the name of the userObject(`rawvalue`) to load I want to follow this hierarchical order :-

```
b036, PersonName (e.g., John Smith) if not available use b037
b037, PersonName (e.g., Smith, John) if not available use b040
b040, KeyNames, a.k.a Last Name (e.g., Smith)
If none of b036, b037 or b040 are found, I do not want to set the "rawvalue" for that record
```

How can I construct my if-else statements or should I use switch case statements to achieve the same?

Comment: It is of string type -> object is a Custom user defined object and its added to a list of similar objects

Comment: In all three if-else block you are doing the same operation. You should create a list of strings with `b036`,`b037` and `b040` to the list and then use`Contains` Linq method on the list to check if `element.Name.LocalName` is in the list and set value of `userObject.rawValue` if it's true

Comment: I want to set the raw value based on which element **"b036"-> "b037" -> "b040"**(this is hierarchical order needed) has a value; if "b036" XElement does not exist it should set the value to whatever is there in XElement tag "b037" else set to "b040"

Comment: @Darshak I believe you need to implement your code in a fundamentally other way, using 2 methods: (1) to find any suitable element according the hierarchy; (2) extract name from the found method. Item (1) should try searching for each element and return first satisfying. Also, check case if there are none of required elements.

Comment: @RustemMustafin can you possibly show me an implementation for this method?

Comment: Do you want to find the interesting `element` and work with `userObject` inside each `elements` or find one over all `elements`?

Comment: @NetMage I want to find one over all `elements`

Comment: I want to basically get all element names which have name as "b036", "b037" and "b040" and assign their corresponding value to the `userObject.rawValue` variable. and I want to set it based on the hierarchial order mentioned above and if none of the xml elements are found then set nothing in the `rawValue` variable.

Comment: My data looks like this:-

`<xmlTag>
<b036>John Smith</b036>
<b037>Smith, John</b037>
<b040>Smith</b040>
</xmlTag>`

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to find the value for the highest of certain elements, do a max search. By rolling your own, you avoid having to scan or test twice.

First, create a variable to represent the precedence of the interesting names:

```
var hierarchy = new[] { "b040", "b037", "b036" };
```

Now setup some variables to remember the maximum candidate found so far:

```
XElement candidate = null;
int candidatePos = -1;
```

Finally, go through all the `XMLElement` values and remember the maximum found:

```
foreach (var element in xmlElements.SelectMany(elements => elements)) {
    var pos = Array.IndexOf(hierarchy, element.Name.LocalName);
    if (pos >= 0) {
        if (candidate == null || pos > candidatePos) {
            candidate = element;
            candidatePos = pos;
        }
    }
}
```

If you found a maximum, you can work with it:

```
if (candidate != null) { //"b036" is a XML element tag name
    UserObject userObject = new UserObject();
    userObject.rawValue = (candidate.Value.Trim()); //note rawvalue is of string type
    // work with userObject
}
```

Comment: I want to set the raw value based on which element **"b036"-> "b037" -> "b040"** has a value; if "b036" XElement does not exist it should set the value to whatever is there in XElement tag "b037" else set to "b040"

Comment: @Darshak This replicates your code. Since you are only referring to one `element` variable, I don't see how your code is changing to whichever element is first.

Comment: I am looking for that part of code to see whichever element exists and comes first I want to set the rawValue to that particular value of the element

Comment: this doesnt seem to be working for me; this gives me only 1 of the values and overrides the previous values set and eventually takes the value of "b040" XElement name and not "b036" if its present and exists

Comment: @Dashak I think you need to show more code explaining how you are setting the `element` variable.

Comment: I added more code to explain the setting of the element variable, let me know if that helps in solving the hierarchical order or return nothing if none of the elements present in XML

Comment: @Darshak I updated my answer. If you don't mind testing twice and an extension method, you could use LINQ, but it really wouldn't be more efficient, just shorter code.